# problema de logica com o textinput do kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Estou fazendo uma espécie de mascara para meu textinput mas estou       tendo alguns problemas com o resultado final.

- a cada 6 números    digitados meu cursor esta retornando uma casa
- ao apagar os valores
  digitados, nos 3 últimos dígitos também estou tento o recuo do cursor
- alguém sabe me dizer o porque? e teria uma solução?

---

codigo exemplo:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import locale



class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
    posicao = 3

    def teste(self):
        id_text = self.ids['my_input']
        

        if len(id_text.text) < 4 and id_text.text == '0,0':
            id_text.text = '0,00'


        elif id_text.text == '':

            id_text.text = '0,00'


        elif len(id_text.text) < 4 and id_text.text != '0,0':
            valor = id_text.text.replace(',','').replace('.','')
            num_formatado = locale.currency(int(valor)/100, grouping=True, symbol=False)

            id_text.text = num_formatado

        else:
            if len(id_text.text) > 4:
                valor = id_text.text[self.posicao:].replace(',','').replace('.','')

                #print('valor:',valor)
                num_formatado = locale.currency(int(valor)/100, grouping=True, symbol=False)

                id_text.text = num_formatado
                if self.posicao > 0:
                    self.posicao -= 1


        print('posicao: ',self.posicao)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

testapp.kv

```
<MyBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,1.5,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.4
        TextInput:
            id: my_input
            text: '0,00'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.8, None
            height: '75dp'
            font_size: 50
            multiline: False
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            on_text: root.teste()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obs: respondendo por outra conta ja que o stackOverflow fica me breckando toda hora com esses montes de regras..

Reaproveitei oque você fez @DoctorXD e fiz algumas alterações e funcionou bem como eu queria, estou fazendo alguns teste ainda antes de implementar no meu código real mas aparentemente ta funcionando bem, acredito que não seja a melhor maneira de fazer mas foi a melhor solução até agora. obg por ter respondido.

ficou assim:

```
from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    import locale
    
    
    
    class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8')
        posicao = 3
    
        def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
            id_text = self.ids['my_input']
            Clock.schedule_once(self.set_cursor_position, 0)
            print(id_text.cursor)
            #execulta a funçao do set_cursor_position com o Clock
    
        def set_cursor_position(self,dt):
            id_text = self.ids['my_input']
            cursor_position = len(id_text.text)
            id_text.cursor = (cursor_position, 0)
    
             # Define a posição do cursor sempre no final
    
    
        def teste(self):
            id_text = self.ids['my_input']
            print('execultado')
    
            if len(id_text.text) < 4 and id_text.text == '0,0':
                id_text.text = '0,00'
                self.on_kv_post(self)
    
    
            elif id_text.text == '':
    
                id_text.text = '0,00'
    
    
            elif len(id_text.text) < 4 and id_text.text != '0,0':
    
                valor = id_text.text.replace(',','').replace('.','')
                num_formatado = locale.currency(int(valor)/100, grouping=True, symbol=False)
    
                id_text.text = num_formatado
                self.on_kv_post(self) #chamo onde preciso
    
            else:
                if len(id_text.text) > 4:
                    valor = id_text.text[self.posicao:].replace(',','').replace('.','')
                    num_formatado = locale.currency(int(valor)/100, grouping=True, symbol=False)
    
                    id_text.text = num_formatado
                    self.on_kv_post(self) #chamo onde preciso
                    if self.posicao > 0:
                        self.posicao -= 1
    
    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyBoxLayout()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        TestApp().run()
```